# non static method cannot be referenced from a static context android

Tags: android, toast

It shows error in Toast.show(); 
I can't get what is the problem. please help

```
     submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               if((feedbackMessage.length()>30)&&(feedbackMessage.length()<500)){ 
               Log.i("rajat",String.valueOf(feedbackMessage));   
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"fewgre",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);   
                 Toast.show();
}
```

Comment: You have to call show from the instance returned from makeText()

Answer (score 4):

`show()` is not a static method of `Toast`, hence you need an instance of `Toast` to access it through the `.` operator, instance returned in this case by the static method `makeText`. So you can either do

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"fewgre",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
```

or call it directly on the returned instance:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"fewgre",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```